debug mode and run mode different result
I am using python 3.11 with win10
My program is simulate multimedia keys.
The program good working debug mode. But when the run mode not working.
Also I used pynput module.
If I put the command line in the main loop, it works in both run modes. But when I put it in DEF, this problem occurs. Could the problem be caused by python?
program aşağıdadır.
import keyboard
import pyautogui
import time
import serial
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, KeyCode
from pynput.keyboard import Key
import pydirectinput # daha çok directx uyumlu oyunlar için kullanılabilir. diğerleri bunda sorunlu.
keyb = Controller()
ser = serial.Serial('COM1', 9600, timeout=.1)

time.sleep(5)
#keyboard.write(str(128))
#keyboard.write("up")

#keyboard.press_and_release("A")
#keyboard.press_and_release('shift+a')
#keyb.press(KeyCode.from_vk(0xAF))# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes

#********* ÖNEMLİ= joystick kontrollerini eski oyun programlarında çalıştırmak isterseniz
# bunun son versiyonu problem yaratıyor.
# bundan dolayı oyun programlarında daha çok directx kullanan oyunlarda çalışmak için 
# bu versiyonu yüklemelisiniz. https://pypi.org/project/pydirectinput-rgx/   ****************

# pydirectinput pyautoguiden oluşturulmuş. onun bazı komutlarını kullanan çok az sayıda komutu olan bir modüldür
# en önemli tarafı directx uyumlu olması. bundan dolayı joystick kullanımı için faydalanabilirsiniz.

# bununla yapılmış bluetooth joystick programı videolarda var. 
# türkçe karakter yazılamaz. 
def volup(key):               #what to do if key pressed. takes value from handleJoyStickAsArrowKeys
    keyb.press(KeyCode.from_vk(0xAF))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    keyb.release(KeyCode.from_vk(0xAF))
    #keyb.tap(KeyCode.from_vk(0xAF))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.press("volumeup")# her volume up 2 birim hareket eder. 
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pyautogui.press("volumeup")# her volume up 2 birim hareket eder. 
    time.sleep(0.1)
    #keyb.tap(KeyCode.from_vk(0xAF))
    #pyautogui.press(key)  #runs pydirectinput using key from (argument)
    #print('UP: ', key)       #remove '#' from print to test data stream


while True:
    data=56
    #time.sleep(3)
    num = ser.readline()
    ser.reset_input_buffer() 
    #num=num[0:2]
    print(num)
    #num="SC186"
    datalen=num
    print(datalen)
    data2=len(datalen)
    if data2>4:
       num=num[0:4] 
       datalen=num
       print(datalen)
       data2=len(datalen)

    if data2>0:
        data3=int(datalen[2:data2])
    else:
        data3=0

    
    data=0
    databak=""
    if data2>0:
        print(data2)
        print (data3)
        print ("data3  ",data3)
        databak=("volumeup")
        #databak=komut_lookup[data3]
        print(" databak : ",databak)
        volup(databak)
        databak=""`

I ran the command line in the main section and it worked.
When I put it in DEF, it worked in debug mode.
It didn't work in RUN mode either.
I tried it with the PYNPUT module.
I tried it with the PYAUTOGUI module
The result is the same.
if you want to watch video about this problem, you can use this link. :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qPgqBMRqDTWmr4WTChsFp_3MefD2y5_n/view?usp=drive_link

Problem solved.
Actually the problem is caused by the Proteus simulator affecting the system. Maybe there is a conflict. This problem was solved with the real ARDUINO test.
When working with Proteus, debug mode is used and since PYTHON adjusts the system according to itself when it stops at a breakpoint, there was no problem when going with STEP.
Now when working with the real circuit, PYTHON executes the commands nicely even if it continues to run in the background.
Both the pynput module and pyautogui work nicely.
